# sed - replacing text with colon

Tags: sed

I have this command:

```
sed -i  "s/a:b/b:c/g" file.txt
```

(in English: replace "a:b" with "b:c" in file.txt)

This doesn't work because of the colons in the subsitution text.
How should I re-write the command?

Comment: What doesn't work? At least GNU sed 4.2.1 (e.g. on Debian) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
-->cat 1
a:bLINE1
a:bLINE2

-->cat 1 | sed 's/a:b/b:c/g'
b:cLINE1
b:cLINE2
```

Comment: [Same here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389141/sed-replacing-text-with-colon#comment20016526_14389141)

Comment: Yeayh, it does. It was not it. It failed due to something else, which I figured out.

Comment: It sounds like a good question - at least now I am sure the colon is not treated as a special character by sed!

Answer (score 9):

In case you want be safe , you can escape the `:` colon

`sed -re "s/a\:b/b\:c/g" temp.txt`